# TypeError: load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'offset' and [WinError 5] Access is denied at same time

Tags: python

I am new in using python. I am trying to run a code and get this type
TypeError: load() got an unexpected keyword argument 'offset'
after few rows of this error I get another one called  [WinError 5] Access is denied at same time.
Is there any solution for the code to complete training process?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WinError 5: Access is denied` usually means that the file your referenced is already opened by another program.

As for the `unexpected argument`, it should be `frame_offset` as per the [offical documentation](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/backend.html#load)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... I have another question if u don't mind ... there is another error  Runtime error: error opening.wav file: system error